# ekf_localization control command

Tags: ros, navigation, sensor-fusion, robot-localization, ekf-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I just saw it now is possible add to the filter a control command, but looking at the code this control applies on the accelerations directly, and not x(t + 1) = A*x(t) + B*u(t).
What model use in the filter?

The command of my robot is linear velocity and angular velocity, How i do it?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237211/ekf_localization-control-command/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2016-06-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the `control_config` can control the input of your integration.
and I think its order is Vx,Vy,Vz,VRoll,Vpitch,Vyaw.

---

Originally posted by [asimay_y](https://answers.ros.org/users/20955/asimay_y/) with karma: 255 on 2016-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0